# hook_preprocess_paragraph is not invoked

Tags: hooks

function my_module_preprocess_paragraph__Paragraphname(&$variables) {
var_dump("Inside para hook");
}

This hook function is not working. Are there any dependencies in there?

Comment: Activate module, flush cache, check typos.

Comment: I did everything even (function my_module_preprocess_paragraph) also not working

Comment: This hook doesn't work when you're using the Display Suite layout for your view mode.

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are working in Drupal. This situation happens all the time.

Usually :

- Check for a typo in the function name.
- Check the file name in which you placed the hook function. Depending on weither you're in a module or a theme, it should be `module_machine_name.module` or `module_machine_name.theme`
- Check the page type you're checking on. In my tests, this hook is not called on page types that does not reference a paragraph entity field reference.
- Hooks are cached, so you must empty the cache after creating a new hook.

Comment: I opened a particular content which has a paragraph. But it is not working. There is no typo also.

Comment: Would  like to help you more, but without any more information, I couldn't. I would suggest to use a debugger to help you tracing the issue.